# DocuSign REST API - Emails with generated PDFs are not sent

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to build project with PHP / Composer library.

When I try to send with Template ID (Which I created and retrieved the ID) everything works fine:

```
-> Email is sent 
-> Document is signed 
-> Done.
```

If I generate PDF and send a request to DocuSign REST services it responds with the same status that email is sent but it is never delivered.

Code:

```
Route::get('docusign-test', function () {

    $client = DocuSign::create();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfs.signature-test');

    try {
        return $client->envelopes->createEnvelope($client->envelopeDefinition([
            'status'        => 'sent',
            'email_subject' => '[DocuSign PHP SDK] - Signature Request Sample',
            'recipients'    => $client->recipients([
                'signers' => [
                    $client->signer([
                        'name'           => 'John Doe',
                        'email'          => 'mytestemail@gmail.com',
                        'client_user_id' => 1,
                        'role_name'      => 1,
                        'recipient_id'   => 1,
                        'tabs'           => $client->tabs([
                            'sign_here_tabs' => [
                                $client->signHere([
                                    'anchor_string'                => 'Sign Here:',
                                    'anchor_x_offset'              => '116',
                                    'anchor_y_offset'              => '-9',
                                    'anchor_ignore_if_not_present' => false,
                                    'anchor_units'                 => 'pixels',
                                    'recipient_id'                 => 1,
                                ]),
                            ],
                        ]),
                    ]),
                ],
            ]),
            'documents'     => [
                $client->document([
                    'document_base64' => base64_encode($pdf->stream()),
                    'name'            => 'test',
                    'document_id'     => 1,
                    'file_extension'  => 'pdf',
                ]),
            ],
        ]));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        dd($e->getResponseBody());
    }

});
```

I have tried few times with Template ID and with generated PDF and always with generated PDF is not delivered.

Sample response:

```
{
    "envelopeId": "fbced4a8-db72-4ffb-b39d-88f260c5eeee",
    "status": "sent",
    "statusDateTime": "2017-12-06T21:29:52.7670000Z",
    "uri": "/envelopes/fbced4a8-db72-4ffb-b39d-88f260c5eeee"
}
```

Note: I'm working on demo.docusign.com, not production.

Comment: Can you please share the code, may be something you are doing wrong in the code? With my DocuSign experience, it seems when you are sending using PDF, you are probably setting clientUserId in your code which is stopping DocuSign to send an email to the sender.

Comment: I have inserted the code. @AmitKBist Thank you for your response.

Comment: OMG @AmitKBist I have removed client_user_id and it works. Thank you so much! Add your answer to answers and I'll make it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, its the same problem which I mentioned in my comment, you are setting clientUserId

```
'client_user_id' => 1,
```

Setting clientUserId means you are informing DocuSign that you will be doing embedded Signing and you are asking DocuSign not to send any email notifications to the customer. And you will be creating the embedded signing URL for the signer and you will be hosting the signing ceremony.